# Multiple selection of ID's (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Is it possible for me to select multiple ID? For example: I am executing this command

```
SELECT 
sum(amount)
FROM 
bets_logs
where
fight_id=1
```

Assumming that I have id that is up to **500** Of course I'll do it one by one... My target is, is there a query that I can select id from 1 to 10. So that I won't do it 1 by one.

Comment: `SELECT flight_id, sum(amount) FROM bets_logs where fight_id in (1,10) GROUP BY flight_id`

Comment: Works like magic. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My target is, is there a query that I can select id from 1 to 10. So
> that I won't do it 1 by one.

You can write the query like following.

```
SELECT fight_id,  sum(amount) 
FROM 
bets_logs
where
fight_id >=1 and fight_id<=10
group by fight_id
```

Comment: This is one is much better. Thank you so much.